# Netty ChannelBuffer in Ver 4.0

Tags: java, netty, nio

I'm migrating a system from Netty ver 3. to Ver 4. I would like to use a string delimiter  in the handler. How do i do this in Netty 4?

```
pipeline.addLast("frameDecoder", new DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder(8192, ChannelBuffers.wrappedBuffer("</message>".getBytes())));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
pipeline.addLast("frameDecoder", new DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder(8192, Unpooled.wrappedBuffer("</message>".getBytes())))
```